# android alert when activity transition is over

Tags: android, animation, android-activity, handler, transition

I want to start an animation right after the activity transition is over. I tried using a handler, but it seems that the duration I give the transition animation is not in milliseconds. Even if it was in milliseconds, it probably will never be accurate since the time between the start of the transition and the time I load the handler with the animation will create a small lag. So if there is some implemented method that helps that will be great, other creative ideas will be much appreciated.

For the activity transition I'm using `overridePendingTransition(R.anim.anim1,R.anim,anim2)`
with animations similar to:

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
     android:zAdjustment="top">  
    <translate android:fromXDelta="-100%p" 
               android:toXDelta="0" 
               android:duration="450" />
</set>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use android:startOffset="milis" inside animation you will implement, where milis is equals to anim1 time duration.